# Setting up Sublime Text 3 w/ a local server for testing

Tags: eclipse, server, sublimetext3, mamp, local

I am taking a course on web development and I haven't been getting any help on how to set up Sublime Text 3 with a local server. I am being taught by some foreigners who can hardly speak English, so when I ask them, they don't really know how to explain it to me. Videos online haven't helped.

They want me to use Eclipse with Apache Tomcat, which I have set up, but I would like to use Sublime Text 3 instead of Eclipse, because I like it much better. I read something about MAMP, but again, I would need help setting it up. If anyone could point me in the right direction or give me a breakdown of what I need to do. My current assignments are with using AJAX & JSON... and then AngularJS. So I need to basically be able to retrieve items from a JSON file and insert them in my HTML, from a local server. I hope I made sense here.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam, as you can see below.

Answer (score 0):

Use livereload, it helps auto refreshing the site, it also compiles files like less, css, html, javascript and more. make sure all your files are in one big folder with sub folders for images etc.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I downloaded it and am using it now, but I'm not sure it is exactly what I'm asking. I need to basically have a virtual server on my Mac so I can do my assignments. So I will have a JSON file with items in it that will be accessed from my html file. For example, I have a home page that will cycle 3 images, stored in a JSON file that are on this virtual server. This is where I am confused. How do I put the JSON on a local server, what local server do I use, etc. Is the JSON file going to be in my workspace folder with all the html/css/js etc? I have Apache Tomcat already.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use Terminal? The simplest way to set up a local server is to navigate to your project folder inside the Terminal and then type `Python -m SimpleHTTPServer`. Then, you will have a server running and you can go to your browser and go to `localhost:8000` as your address.